# Cordova Android white space between status bar and header

Tags: android, css, cordova, intel-xdk

I've done almost everything but seems like I cant get rid of the white space between header and status bar as seen in the image

[image: Bug Image]

I am using Intel XDK version 3987 using Cordova plugin.

Any help to eliminate this error will be highly appreciated!

This is my source code:

```
pastebin.com/fPWJmiD8
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several days of headbanging, trials and errors and detective work, I was able to find the real culprit.

The problem was caused because jQuery Mobile framework automatically on the runtime added the following classes to the header div having data-role="header":

```
class="ui-header ui-bar-inherit"
```

Those classes created an unwanted margin between the status bar and the header.

However, this problem was solved by removing those classes using jQuery during the runtime execution of the application.

Answer (score 1):

To me it seems that your header-elements (`data-role="header"`) have got a border-width of 1px that causes the whole content to move downwards.

Have you already tried to remove the border from each header?

CSS:

```
.ui-header{
  border: none !important;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: thank you very much for taking interest in my problem, as you suggested, I added .ui-header code provided by you but unfortunately, it doesn't seem to solve the problem.

Comment: No problem. Unfortunately I can not have a look on your init-dev/app.js files  to run your app properly. Do you run any css-changing code in these files? if yes, remove these files to check whether that causes the problem. I can say that without these files the white bar is gone with me. Good luck!

Comment: here is my init-dev.js https://pastebin.com/QnijdXuS   I also have tried to remove the code which changes css in the JS but still the problem persists. I also have tried to remove init-dev.js but no gain as well.

Comment: I was able to solve my problem and I have also posted my solution to my own answer. Thank you very much for showing your concern about my problem.